# Location gives wrong speed

Tags: android, google-maps, location, android-gps

I am developing an app for checking behavior of driver. I have set check in my code

```
if (location.getSpeed > 4){
     stratTrip();
}
```

that if vehicle(location.getSpeed()) speed is greater than 4 m/s then start the trip and track the driver, All thing are going well but one thing which I couldn't find any solution for that is "Mobile is lying on the table and location gives more speed, some times 6000 m/s etc, Due to this trip is started, which is not required." I don't know how to handle this. I have set accuracy in between 1 and 48. 
any help will be appropriated.
Thanks

Comment: GPS data may be noisy and there's no one standard answer to give. You'll have to see what kind of filtering/averaging/other logic suits your case. You could e.g. check that it's not just a single GPS update that shows movement and of course your example of 6000 m/s must be an error in case of a car, so ignore those kind of values in your code.

Comment: When your device is inside a building and not moving, GPS gives wrong data. for that you have to put another check for speed less than some certain value.

Comment: Also set one more criteria, accuracy <= 50  .

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thanks for answering. actually in car or motorcycle gps gives perfect values. it is in case of being inside the building.

Comment: @Danger I am agree with your answer, I am setting accuracy<= 50 , then I will test it. Thanks